# Remove a specific event on fullcalendar using a custom function

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am attempting to remove a single event using below function, just wondering why it's removing all events instead of the supplied title or id, I am calling it using on `drop` function.

```
 function  removeEvent(id){
    console.log("we remove id " + id);

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents',  function(event){

        return event.title = id;

    });
```

Comment: How is `removeEvents` defined?

Comment: `removeEvents` is a default function of fullcalendar? https://fullcalendar.io/docs1/event_data/removeEvents/

Comment: _If idOrFilter is omitted, all events are removed._... The call should be as `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', id);`

Comment: Ow! so removing a single event is not possible?

Comment: I've updated my comment above, there should be a right version of code you need.

Comment: Thanks for you reply i manage to remove it by removing the white space on my title.